# Accessing child node created in separate function

Tags: javascript, parent-child

I am new to js and am curious about how to remove a child node that was appended in a different function.  For example, in the function below, the element `p` is set as variable `empty` which is then appended to `listingEl`.

```
  var empty = document.createElement('p');
  empty.innerHTML = '<p><div>' + 'Drag map to populate results' + '</div></p>'; 

  empty.style.color = "#FFFFF0";
  empty.style.fontSize = 125 + "%";
  listingEl.appendChild(empty);
```

How could I access this child `empty` in another function in order to change its `innerHTML` for example or to remove it completely?

`listingEl.removeChild(empty)` does not work when executed in a different function, however when I create a new element and *append* it to 
`listingEl` in a different function, that works.  For example:

```
var back = document.createElement('p');
                back.innerHTML = '<p><div>' + 'Hit back arrow to see results' + '</div></p>';
                back.style.color = "#FFFFF0";
                back.style.fontSize = 125 + "%";
                listingEl.appendChild(back);
```

Why does `appendChild()` work but `removeChild(empty)` not?

Comment: Return `empty` from the first function, and assign it to a variable in the calling function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign an id to p when appending

```
var empty = document.createElement('p');
  empty.innerHTML = '<p><div>' + 'Drag map to populate results' + '</div></p>'; 

  empty.style.color = "#FFFFF0";
  empty.style.fontSize = 125 + "%";
  empty.id="appended-p"
  listingEl.appendChild(empty);
```

and then when you have to remove then use,

```
var elem = document.getElementById("appended-p");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

If you have multiple dynamically generated p tags then you can maintain a counter and allot unique IDs to each appended p tag